# jquery attribute selector in ul li

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a ul like this:

```
<ul class = "abc">
<li>
  <span class = "X">
     <a href="" title="alpha">alpha</a>
  </span>
  <span class = "Y"> 
  </span>
  <span class = "Z"> 
  </span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class = "X">
     <a href="" title="beta">beta</a>
  </span>
  <span class = "Y"> 
  </span>
  <span class = "Z"> 
  </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Inside ul where class is abc I want to select li with a having title="alpha".  How can I do this using jquery?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I was trying something like this:                                var desiredLI = $('ul.abc li').each(function () {
                   var current = this;
                   var span = $(this).find('span.X a');
                   if (span.title == jsonResult.filename)
                          return current;
                            });

Comment: None of the `<li>` elements in your example have a title of alpha.

Comment: Enough amount of research needs to be done before posting the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go...

```
$('ul.abc').find('a[title=alpha]').closest('li');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 $("ul.abc a[title=alpha]").closest('li')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( 'ul.abc li' ).find( 'a[title=alpha]' );
```